# Connect dodged points per subject in grouped boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some grouped data where I want position dodged boxplots and position dodged points and I'd like to add a line connecting the points within a group.

```
library(tidyverse)
mock_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Subject, ~Marker, ~Cell_type, ~Value,
        "1",     "A",        "B",    70L,
        "2",     "A",        "B",    80L,
        "3",     "A",        "B",    90L,
        "1",     "A",        "T",     5L,
        "2",     "A",        "T",    10L,
        "3",     "A",        "T",    15L,
        "1",     "B",        "B",     1L,
        "2",     "B",        "B",     2L,
        "3",     "B",        "B",     3L,
        "1",     "B",        "T",    99L,
        "2",     "B",        "T",    90L,
        "3",     "B",        "T",    99L
  )
```

What I'd like to see is:
[image]

I have tried a variety of groupings in geom_line but can't seem to get the expected output

```
mock_data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Marker, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Cell_type), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(aes(col = Subject, group = Cell_type), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Subject), lty = 2, col = "black")
```

gives me:
[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could facet by Maker and put Cell_type in the "x" axis

```r
mock_data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Cell_type, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Cell_type), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(aes(col = Subject, group = Cell_type), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Subject), lty = 2, col = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~Marker, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank()
    )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think this is the best solution. If you want to avoid faceting you will probably need a hacky solution using `geom_segment()`

Comment: I agree. I have actually got additional facets in the real dataset but I can probably use patchwork or cowplot to align them horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

For general interest, here is an alternative solution that does not require faceting. However it does require "artificially" generating the x coordinates of the line segments.

```
segment_positions <- mock_data |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Subject,Marker), names_from = Cell_type, values_from = Value) |>
  mutate(x1 = as.numeric(Marker == 'B') + 1 - .75/4, x2 = as.numeric(Marker == 'B') + 1 + .75/4)

mock_data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Marker, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Cell_type), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(aes(col = Subject, group = Cell_type), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), size = 3) +
  geom_segment(data = segment_positions, aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = B, yend = T), lty = 2, col = "black")
```

Notice that the offset of the x coordinates is `0.75/4` because the total dodge width is 0.75. That means the boxplots are each offset by half that total width (`0.75/2`) on each side of the dodge. Because the points are in the middle of the boxplots, they are offset by half of the offset width of each boxplot (`0.75/4`).

[image]